# Scrolling & Layout Problems with ExpandableListView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, expandablelistview

I am developing an app which needs a unscrollable header at the top, Scrollable `ExpandableListView` in the middle and then unscrollable footer at the bottom. see the image below

[image: sample image]

The problem is Scrollable property of `ExpandableListView`, when i expand parent view of the `ExpandableListView`, list scroll under footer, unscrollable, which is the problem. See below
[image: problem]

here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F2B1DBF3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/callheader"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/callerheader" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/exSavedVoiceList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/callheader"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/drawableanimation"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >
</ExpandableListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llbottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#ff33b5e5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSaveNewVoice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff33b5e5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_new"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/setting"
        android:drawablePadding="40dp"
        android:text="@string/add_new"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If i put `android:layout_below="@+id/exSavedVoiceList"` in `llbottom` (`LinearLayout`), footer moves below if `parent view` is expanded.

[image: problem 2]

Please provide a solution with a possible explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#F2B1DBF3"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
    <include
            android:id="@+id/callheader"
            layout="@layout/callerheader" />

    <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/exSavedVoiceList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/callheader"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/drawableanimation"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llbottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff33b5e5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/bSaveNewVoice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff33b5e5"
                android:contentDescription="@string/add_new"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/setting"
                android:drawablePadding="40dp"
                android:text="@string/add_new"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: working perfectly fine but can you tell me what is the problem with `RelativeLayout`

Comment: we gave android:layout_weight="1" to ExpandableListView if we have LinearLayout as parent and ur case LinearLayout it better solution.

Comment: i understood what you did in `LinearLayout` but i just want to know what is wrong in using `RelativeLayout`. Specially why bottom bar also becomes scrollable along with `ExpandableListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add android:layout_above="@+id/llbottom" to your expandablelistview. and don't add android:layout_below="@+id/exSavedVoiceList" to your llbottom layout.

Comment: now when i expand all the `parent views` then the last one goes under `llbottom`